# Browser viewpoint position of a control

Tags: javascript

I need to get java script code to find a HTML control position based on the browser screen.

Does anyone knows something about this or can point me in right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

Try `element.getBoundingClientRect()`.

[MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect)